# How to make an URL in a MVC page independt of a '/id' is present or not

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC application which is used by an administrator and some users. The users can see a list of their own tools on a page, with a URL:

> /Tool/List

The administrator can see all the users lists pages with a URL like:

> /Tool/List/1234

Where 1234 is the id of the user.

In order to download a list of the tools in an Excel-file the page has the following:

```
<a onclick='window.open("../ExcelListe");'>Download</a>
```

Which works fine when you are the administrator. But when you are a user (without the '/id' in the URL) the HTML must be:

```
<a onclick='window.open("ExcelListe");'>..</a>// without ../
```

I can solve the problem by making a test on the URL in the filterContext and making some if-else in the razor code. But is there a smarter way to solve this problem?

I have only registered the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC it is better to never use fixed or hardcoded links, it is always better to use a helper, in this case `Url.Action()`.

The link to `ExcelListe` looks to be at the same level as `List`, so I'll assume that ExcelListe is also an action method of the ToolController.

Put this in your View (e.g. List.cshtml):

```
@{
    var link = Url.Action("ExcelListe");
}
<a onclick='window.open("@(link)");'>Download</a>
```

You can tweak the parameters of `Url.Action()` to get the URL that you need.